# Img one('load', ...) doesn't always trigger in IE - I give up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Ok this is just doesn't make any sense and it's so redicoulous, and I just don't get it.

So, im having a function to make pictures.

```
function mk_image(src, alt, title, link) {
       img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.id='ShowC_Img_'+count_image;
        count_image+=1;
        img.width = 960;
        img.height = 320;
        img.alt = alt;
        img.style.display='none';
        img.setAttribute('border',"0");
        return [img,'url('+src+')',link];
    }
```

Then I make array of 13 elements this way, something lke:

```
var items = [/* mk_image('image_source', 'alt', 'title', 'link'), etc... */
```

then I run through the array and make following:

```
for (i=0; i<items.length;i++){
              $(items[i][0]).one('load', function(){ 
//blablabla
}).each(function(){
                if(this.complete || (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) == 6)) 
                $(this).trigger("load");})
            .error(function(){alert('shit');}); 
        }
```

And guess what then. Sometimes it triggers 8 pictures in IE, - sometimes ... all of them, I just don't get it............
Works 100% PERFECT in Google chrome though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages from IE?

Comment: try to set the src attribute after you observe the loading event... in IE this is triggered synchronously... additionally you could do `this.complete || this.readyState == 4 || this.readyState == "complete"` as this works pretty well in IE<=8 to check whether they are loaded ("complete" is HTML5)

Comment: The error event never triggers. What error messages do you mean btw?

Comment: I've just inserted your code to check state - the result is the same. What do you mean setting Src after loading?...

Comment: first of all I somehow deleted a line... in IE this is triggered synchronously (and therefore there is no load event) IF the image was already requested and is available in the memory... setting the src after the load event observing: first create the image, then do `.one("load", function() { /* ... */ })`, and then do `img.src = src;`, that is more reliable...

Comment: Ah I think I got what you meant, I'll try to add Src before load with JQ ?

Comment: when reading my just posted answer I think it should also work without setting the src afterwards... but might be the reason

Comment: I mean first when making an array in the beginning of the script,
and then once more with JQuery just before the .load binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok since it seems it gets a little bit bigger, try to use the following to debug a bit more in detail (once with setting the src attribute directly and once without):

```
function mk_image(src, alt, title, link) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.id='ShowC_Img_'+count_image;
    count_image+=1;
    img.width = 960;
    img.height = 320;
    img.alt = alt;
    img.style.display='none';
    img.setAttribute('border',"0");
    return [img,'url('+src+')',link];
}

var items = [/* mk_image('image_source', 'alt', 'title', 'link'), etc... */

function onLoad(img) {
  console.log(img || this); // check this output (are all images displayed?)
}

for (i=0; i<items.length;i++){
  $(items[i][0]).one("load", onLoad)
  .each(function(){
    if (this.complete || this.readyState === 4 || this.readyState === "complete") {
      onLoad(this);
    }
  })
  .error(function(){alert('shit');}); 
}
```

Comment: Well I console log does nothing for some reason... I can't seem to find anything about images in the console log.

Comment: I'm sort of fixed it, I put attr('src',src). just before I make one('load'); However it take the whole page to load before it starts to download the images.